# c++ перемещение и неизменяемый класс

Tags: c++, классы, move

Я хочу разобраться в следующей ситуации.

Допустим, имеется класс **A**, объекты которого после конструирования не могут изменяться, предоставляя лишь геттеры для получения доступа к своим данным. То есть, валидность создаваемого объекта класса **A** контролируется в конструкторе. И на этот факт опирается очень многое, например, работа других классов, которые пользуются объектами класса **A**.

Проблема в том, что классу **A** нужен конструктор перемещения и перемещающий оператор присваивания. После перемещения объекта класса **A** изначальный объект становится невалидным:

```
A a_1{ 1, 2, 3 };
A a_2 = move(a_1);

do_something(a_1);// Беда...
```

И я не совсем понимаю, что делать в этой ситуации...

С объектами изменяемых классов таких проблем, как правило, нет.
Например, объект **std::vector** после перемещения становится пуст и может использоваться дальше:

```
vector<float> vf_1 { 1.f, 2.f };
vector<float> vf_2 = move(vf_1);

vf_1.push_back(3.f);// OK
```

Мои вопросы:

1) Является ли эта особенность с перемещением объекта неизменяемого класса нормой?

2) Что с этим делать? Ставить пометки большими красными буквами о том, что объект такого неизменяемого класса после перемещения становится невалиден, и либо не должен использоваться, либо должен вновь вызывать конструктор, чтобы сформировать валидное состояние?

Это неудобная ситуация, потому что бывает очень сложно отследить, выполняются ли специфичные требования для таких объектов в процессе работы программы...

PS. Во многих книжках при описании семантики перемещения применяется странная фраза: **после перемещения объект имеет корректное, но неопределенное состояние**. Но нигде не говорится, что с этим делать.

Comment: Как-то плохо сочетаются "неизменяемый класс" и "перемещение"...

Comment: Я заметил) Но ведь объекты такого класса после конструирования не могут менять свое состояние, не считая случаев перемещения...

Comment: И, допустим, копирование таких объектов - либо очень затратная операция, либо вообще невозможная. Так что перемещение однозначно необходимо.

Comment: Тогда объект уже не является неизменяемым.

Comment: Разве перемещение классифицируется как изменение? Вроде бы нет.

Comment: А как что он по-Вашему классифицируется? Вот у Вас есть яблоко, в нём есть мякоть. Вы нарекаете яблоко неизменным. Потом перемещаете мякоть яблока в другое место. Оно что осталось неизменным? Если у объекта нет методов, которые его изменяют, это не делает него неизменяемым, просто нет методов для изменения. Только один, перемещающий конструктор. А он перемещает этот объект как любой другой. Вот и всё.

Comment: Тогда получается, что мы просто отказываемся от семантики перемещения, которую ввели в язык как раз для того, чтобы не копировать тяжелые/некопируемые объекты. Это не решение проблемы. Я считаю, что нужно разобраться с тем, что значит **корректное, но неопределенное** состояние. Возможно, решение проблемы кроется как раз в этой формулировке. Но я не могу найти никакой информации по этой проблеме.

Comment: Если объект неизменяемый - его можно только копировать, создавая **новый** объект.

Comment: Например, представим, что объект возвращается из функции и передается в какой-то контейнер. Дважды конструировать и удалять объект? А если он уникальный и не может быть скопирован? Плохой вариант, который только множит проблемы.

Comment: Я всегда считал что после операции переноса вторым объектом пользоваться уже нельзя просто так. Он либо удаляется (при выходе из области видимости), либо заново инициализируется какими-то полезными данными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все гарантии, касательно самописного класса, устанавливаются программистом, этот класс написавшим. Т.е. Вы сами определяете, в каком состоянии будет находится объект после перемещения, стандарт С++ не налагает на программиста никаких ограничений. Все объекты стандартной библиотеки подчиняются правилу, описанному в **[lib.types.movedfrom]**:

> Objects of types defined in the C++ standard library may be moved from
>   (15.8). Move operations may be explicitly specified or implicitly
>   generated. Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall
>   be placed in a valid but unspecified state.

Что это значит? Это значит, что после того, как объект класса стандартной библиотеки был перемещён, с ним можно продолжать работать. Но его внутреннее состояние неизвестно, т.е. что вернут запросы типа `size()`, `capacity()` и прочие — неизвестно.

Это довольно неплохой ориентир для написания собственных классов, т.е. после перемещения, объекты Ваших классов можно продолжать использовать. На практике же, минимальным и достаточным требованием для объекта после перемещения является его корректное удаление деструктором. Т.е. при завершении времени жизни объекта, не должно произойти никаких неприятностей. В остальном же — никаких гарантий, т.к. использовать объект после того, как он был перемещён семантически некорректно.

Comment: Большое спасибо